# unable to get the results using where and join condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to get the results like `select * from bookdetails where display_id = $id with few foreign key join condition`

I have written the following query but it is showing error like:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\project at line432` i.e  *if ($query->num_rows() > 0)...

Model.php

```
public function get_all_book_list_atHomeTop($id, $limit, $start)
{
    $this->load->database();  
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);  
    $this->db->get_where('bookdetails', array('display_id' => $id));  

    //-------join condition ------------------


    //------------Ends here Join condition  
    $query = $this->db->get(); 

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing table name in `get()` function:

```
 $query = $this->db->get('bookdetails');
```

Or you can simply replace it with `get_where()` statement you have at the beginning:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('bookdetails',array('display_id'=>$id));
```

Comment: New Doubt: i want to add in my above query a order by case. i.e:  `orderby auth_lastname` . How to do this?

Comment: Just put this above the `get` line (or above the joins): `$this->db->order_by('auth_lastname', 'ASC');`